# Mystery duplicated SIM contacts

Tags: contacts, sim-card

I recently noticed that while searching for contacts I see the same SIM contacts repeated more than 20 times. In the settings for contacts it says I have 5795 contacts on the SIM card but it's almost all the same contacts repeated over and over again. If I delete one of those contacts every other with the same name is also removed.

I have a HTC Desire that runs Android 2.2. I synchronize contacts with Exchange, Google and Facebook but I don't see how that would affect the contacts on the SIM.

Any thoughts on why this happens and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never actually found the underlying problem but by deleting all contacts on the SIM I at least didn't have to scroll through hundreds of duplicates anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Are the contacts also duplicated in your gmail address book?

If it is just on your SIM, it might be worth going into your carrier and getting a new SIM card. It is possible that the SIM card itself is corrupted somehow.

Comment: They weren't duplicated in any other place. I "solved" the problem by deleting all my contacts on the SIM.

Comment: Really? It's not nearly a solution but only a lousy workaround.

Comment: @Jonas: Well, if the problem went away and never came back, I would call it a "solution" even if you didn't find the underlying problem. That way if someone else has the same problem and googles for it, they'll see your "workaround" and know it might help them.